# Sending Post Request to server in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want send an post request to Api server to update my article views count. I am able to do this via Postman by running http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateViews/19    (19 is article id).

I tried http.post() method but could not send request to server.

I just want to send post request whenever anyone open the article detail page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is the sample code for flutter post request using http package.

```
var response = await http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateViews/19',
body:{your post body goes here},
headers : {headers as per your backend needs}
);
```

after above code you can handle the result of the post request, you can send some success code and error code as response from backend.

[for further knowledge visit](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data)

Comment: but I doesn't want post  any data, so can I remove body and header?

Comment: yes you can remove.